# Проблема с биндингом

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть разметка xaml

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentItems}"
          LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"
          RowHeaderWidth="50" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFB0B0B0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFB0B0B0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" Header="Реестровый номер" SortDirection="{Binding OrderBy,ElementName=ancestor,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource OrderToSortConverter}}" Width="110" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ValidFrom, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}" Header="Действует с" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ValidTo, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}" Header="Действует по" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Subject}" Header="Кому выдан" Width="300"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Users}" Header="Список пользователей, к которым привязан сертификат" CanUserSort="False" Width="300" ToolTipService.ToolTip="qwe" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Здесь `ancestor` = это имя самого UserControl'а, в котором находится таблица. Так вот я тут получаю ошибку биндинга

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=OrderBy; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=34728767); target property is
>   'SortDirection' (type 'Nullable`1')

Почему столбцы не видят элемент по имени? Как мне это исправить?